# How to remove testing environment form react-native-iap in Production React Native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, subscription, in-app-subscription, react-native-iap

I have implemented the subscription on iOS and android via `react-native-iap`. It's working fine on **testing on google play** and **testflight**, but when the app goes to production in iOS and Android, it still shows the testing environment.

How do I change the subscription sandbox environment to production?

Comment: have you figured out something?